# Best way to examine the values of a pin?

Tags: pic, serial

New to Pic and microcontrollers in general. I have a PIC16f1779 chip and I want to read the values of an ADC pin (RD1) that is hooked up to a potentiometer. I was wondering how I can see the values of pin RD1. Is there any similar thing to Arduino's simple read() function?  From my research there's not, without setting up a serial connection. So what's the best way to look at RD1? Do I need to interpret the values from the memory view of MPLab, and if so how would I do that?Thanks in advance

Comment: There is a setup procedure you need to go through to configure the ADC and read values from it. That information can be found in datasheets, application notes (app notes), programming manuals, and code examples.

Comment: Get the datasheet and go to Chapter 16. Start there. Make sure you know how to read Figure 16-1, in particular. If you can't make sense of it, the rest of the documentation will still be important but of far less help to you. You need to write code. I think the assembler tool comes free, but you normally pay for the C compiler for Microchip products (though you can avoid that, too, with some work.)